# Python string format x or less digits

Tags: python-3.x, string, formatting

Is there a easy one-liner in python 3.x to print a number with x or less decimal places?

I want

```
numbers = [7, 7.7, 7.77, 7.777]

for number in numbers:
    print("{:.less than 3}".format(number))
```

to return

```
7
7.7
7.77
7.78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `round` numbers to desired precision:

```
numbers = [7, 7.7, 7.77, 7.777]

for number in numbers:
    print(round(number, 2))

# 7
# 7.7
# 7.77
# 7.78
```

Motivated from @JussiNurminen's answer, you can also do:

```
for number in numbers:
    print(f'{number:.3g}')
```

Comment: I didn't use `{:.3g}` because i don't want 7000 to be converted to 7e+03, should have specified that. Didn't think about just rounding it :D. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for number in numbers:
    print('%.3g' % number)
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.